# Understand Working File Upload Solution

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I've written the method below that is called by my doPost method to parse `multipart/form-data` given in the request. It all works great, I just don't really understand what is going on. If anyone could break down the three lines in my try I would really appreciate it. I've read through the [Apache Commons File Upload documentation](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) but it's just not making sense to me and I hate writing code that I do not fully understand. In particular, I would like to know what is actually happening when the factory and upload objects are created.

```
public static List<FileItem> parseFormRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    List<FileItem> items = null;

    try 
    {
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    } 
    catch (FileUploadException error) 
    {
        System.out.println("UploadFileServlet - Error With File Parsing - " + error.getMessage());
    }

    return items;
}
```

**BONUS HELP!**

I also get a warning under `upload.parseRequest(request)` that says `Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<FileItem>`. If anyone could explain this too that would really help me get what I've done. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factory is just a helper, i'll explain later. The main work is done by the `ServletFileUpload`.

`ServletFileUpload` will scan through all the uploaded files (using an Iterator which parses the MIME stuff and knows how to deal with the boundary markers, content length etc.).

For each uploaded file, the parse method asks the `FileItemFactory` to create a local representation for the uploaded file and then copies the contents from memory (e.g. from the HTTP POST request, which is held in memory) to the actual file on disk.

Simplified, the procedure is as follows:

- Get next uploaded file
- Ask factory for a local file ("FileItem")
- Copy content from in-memory (from HttpServletRequest) to local file (a java.io.File in case of a DiskFileItemFactory)
- Loop until end of HTTP request is reached

See the sources of the following classes for details

- org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(RequestContext)
- org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.FileItemIteratorImpl.FileItemStreamImpl

This design allows to switch to another storage facility for files, for example:
You could replace the DiskFileItemFactory with your own DatabaseFileItemFactory, so the uploaded files get stored in a database instead of a local file on the server. The code changes would only affect a single line and the rest of commons-fileupload can be use as-is (e.g. the parsing of the HTTP request, the iterating over the uploaded
files etc.)

For the second question: commons-fileupload seems to be Java 1.4 compatible, so the return type of `parseRequest()`
is actually an un-typed `java.util.List` - it's missing the declaration that the list only contains FileItem objects (e.g. `java.util.List<FileItem>`).
Since you declared your variable `items` to be of type `List<FileItem>`, the Java compiler warns you about this mismatch.

In this case, you did it correctly and you may ignore the warning by adding the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
public static List<FileItem> parseFormRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
{
   ...
```

Comment: +1 because I was nearly finished writing a very similar response, but yours is better worded. The DatabaseFileItemFactory idea is good in clustered environments where future requests might need access to the uploaded data. Where a temporary local file would be available only on the node that received the original request, the database entry's key could be stored in the session and cheaply replicated to other nodes for better failover handling.

Comment: I'm confused with DiskFileItemFactory. How is this writing to a file, and where is it writing to since I did not clarify a location. Does it just write to a file and then delete it right after?

Comment: "DiskFileItemFactory keeps their content either in memory, for smaller items, or in a temporary file on disk, for larger items. The size threshold, above which content will be stored on disk, is configurable, as is the directory in which temporary files will be created.". You need to use FileItem.write(yourFile) to save the uploaded file to somewhere where it's not cleaned up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spend some time in the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html).

From what I can gather, the `ServletFileUpload` instance uses the factory you supplied to actually create the file instances that are in the request.  You used a factory that writes the files to disk; there are other options though (e.g. memory).  By specifying the factory, you are specifying the types of Files that are created.

When you call

`upload.parseRequest(request)`

the `ServletFileUpload` instance goes thru the request data and actually creates the files it finds, using the factory, and returns them to you in a list.

If you look at the `parseRequest` [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html) you will notice that that method only returns a `List`. In your code, you are assigning that returned list to a `List<FileItem>`.  That requires a cast, which is why you get the compiler warning.

Comment: I don't understand why I would get a warning if I am assigning a list to a list

Comment: You are assigning a `List<FileItem>` to a List

Comment: So I need to do a (List<FileItem>) cast

Comment: You don't; it's doing it for you.

Comment: So is there anything I can write to get rid of the warning?

Comment: add the SuppressWarnings annotation

Comment: And when you say it's writing my files to a disk what disk is it writing them to? I never specify one.

Answer (score -1):

I need the java code that is used to invoke this function...
I need the Servlet code that is used to add parameters to the HttpServletRequest